# Monitors and RPi

Tags: hdmi, screen

Why isn't there any definitive answer on monitors? It didn't take me much research to find the right Wi-Fi dongle with the edimax being the most popular or keyboards, for example. However, why is it harder to find a definitive list of monitors for the RPi?

Answer (score 3):

If your monitor has HDMI port then is good to go. Othervise you need to have active HDMI to VGA convertor so you can connect to it. No RPI supported monitor list is needed, just look for HDMI support.

Comment: Also if it's a tv with a yellow composite input then it will definitely work, too.  Just like you won't find a list of compatible USB keyboards either :)

Comment: Yeah, Ive used my TV but im looking to make a workstation so id much rather use a desktop setup